# Supplying default options for error_messages_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a website with several forms that all pass the same set of arguments to `error_messages_for`. Is there a way for me to configure rails to use my default arguments other than creating a helper method which wraps `error_messages_for` with my arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not. The [error_messages_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper.html#M001694) function doesn't relies on any options.

So I guess the best solution is, as you say, to create a helper method to retrieve your arguments.

```
def my_default_error_options(options = {})
    { :value => true }.merge!(options)
end

error_messages_for my_default_error_options
```

And if you need some extra options specifically for one call :

```
error_messages_for my_default_error_options({:value => false})
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick read of the code suggest you can't.  I'd go with the helper route, or monkey patch `error_messages_for`.